# Microservice code reuse strategy for static classes

Tags: c#, microservices, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, .net-core

Hope this is the right place to post an opinion-based question like this. I'm in the process of converting an aging API monolith to a set of .NET 5/C#-based microservices and working on the code reuse strategy. Of course, this is a hot topic, and there are half a dozen or more different ways of approaching it, but what I'd like to be able to do is have a set of shared libraries that can be updated dynamically without having to recompile/redeploy (or, ideally, even stop/restart) the microservices that leverage them. Maybe I'm old-fashioned, but the idea of duplicating and having to maintain the same code in dozens of microservices just doesn't seem practical, and for performance reasons, setting all this functionality up as individual microservices, themselves, isn't practical. All that by way of explaining why I'm trying to do this.
The solution I've been exploring is to use the overload of Assembly.Load() that takes byte arrays for the assembly and its PDB file. This way the file is not locked on disk and can be updated as needed. A FileSystemWatcher alerts the service of a change to the assembly, and DI -- using AddScoped() and constructor injection -- handles the plumbing. Here's a simplified example:

Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);

        foreach (string path in Program.GetAppSettings("IOCAssemblies"))
            LoadAssembly(path, ref services);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseMvc();
    }

    private static void LoadAssembly(string pathToAssemblyFile, ref IServiceCollection services)
    {
        FileInfo dll = new(pathToAssemblyFile);
        FileInfo pdb = new(pathToAssemblyFile.Replace(".dll", ".pdb"));
        Assembly assm = Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(dll.FullName), pdb.Exists ? File.ReadAllBytes(pdb.FullName) : null);
        FileSystemWatcher fsw = new(dll.DirectoryName, dll.Name)
        {
            EnableRaisingEvents = true,
            NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.CreationTime | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.Size
        };
        FileSystemEventHandler handler = (s, e) => 
        {
            byte[] dllBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(pathToAssemblyFile);
            byte[] pdbBytes = pdb.Exists ? File.ReadAllBytes(pdb.FullName) : null;
            assm = Assembly.Load(dllBytes, pdbBytes);
        };

        fsw.Created += handler;
        fsw.Changed += handler;

        foreach (Type t in assm.GetExportedTypes())
            services.AddScoped(t.GetInterfaces()[0], isp => Activator.CreateInstance(assm.GetType(t.FullName)));
    }
}
```

Sample controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    public TestController(IUtilities util)
    {
        _util = util;
    }

    private readonly IUtilities _util;

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get() =>
        Ok(_util.Test());
}
```

And this is the simple Utilities class and its interface that I'm using only for illustration purposes:

```
public class Utilities : IUtilities
{
    public string Test() =>
        "Test 1";
}

public interface IUtilities
{
    string Test();
}
```

This all works beautifully for instance classes. The problem comes with static classes, specifically those used to define extension methods. Obviously, standard DI doesn't work for static classes, and I've really been struggling to find a solution.

**Full disclosure:** I've been told that I'm trying to negate what little practical meaning the term "microservices" has, that this approach is, "a coupled distributed and brittle mess that is easily broken," and that these sorts of services, "should be self contained, part of a CDCI pipeline, be independent of any other service, and should be able to be developed and deployed without conflict." While I agree with that last statement, I don't think the approach I'm pursuing is in conflict with it. Services architected this way would be no more dependent on each other than they would if using a shared DLL. (Or is even that an anti-pattern when it comes to microservices?) They would also be able to be independently developed and deployed via a CI/CD pipeline. Basically, I'm just trying to create a shared library that can be updated dynamically.

Like I alluded to above, maybe I'm a dinosaur and have just had DRY and similar principles beaten into me for so long that I can't comprehend anything else, but it's really hard to believe that the best approach to this sort of thing is to completely duplicate all shared code in every service (likely 60+ of them), then change it in multiple places anytime it needs to be modified. From my research, though, there only seem to be a few alternatives, like the ones mentioned here: [The Dilemma of Code Reuse in Microservices](https://blog.bitsrc.io/the-dilemma-of-code-reuse-in-microservices-a925ff2b9981). Heck, maybe I just need to abandon the term "microservices" and call these "miniservices" or something. (j/k) I just want to make maintenance and support of them as easy as possible.

Does anyone have an approach to this that I haven't come across? Any opinions are welcome.

Comment: Why would you go through all of this effort rather than using blue/green deployments or other approaches to zero-downtime releases?

Comment: One reason is that, even if I use blue/green, A/B, canary or something like that, I would still have to deploy 60+ microservices every time the shared code changed. The amount of red tape involved in that, due to the change management procedures at my company, would make it prohibitive. It would pretty much negate the advantages of microservices.

Comment: You have to deploy 60+ assemblies every time the shared code changes anyways? And I’m pretty sure any company with a change management process will promptly fire you if they find out that you’re circumventing it…

Comment: I think Telasnyn has a point. Hot-updating a shared lib on which 60+ microservices depend has a certain risk of breaking all those 60 microservices in production at once if something goes wrong.  And the DRY principle does not say that all your microservices must us the same version of the lib at all times in production, you can be perfectly DRY with one lib which is developed iteratively in one place, but deployed in specific versions together with the related microservice deliberately, only when the change in the lib will also change the visible behaviour of the service,...

Comment: ... of course, that may sometimes mean to deploy all those 60+ services together with the lib, for example, when there was a severe security bug fixed in the lib - but that will only affect a few percentage of your deployments.

Comment: As a complete aside to your question, you may want to check out the [.NET Support Policy](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core) as .NET 5 goes out of support in six months time and so probably isn't a good choice of target for converting your code to.

Comment: I suspect you are dividing your microservices wrongly. If 60 services use the same logic, and it is paramount that they always use exactly the same version of that logic, then that logic is a bounded context of its own and can be made into its own microservice. If that is not worth the bother, then your code is likely still a monolith, just one that is now being deployed in chunks not because it made logical sense to do so but because you could get away with doing it. Telastyn and Doc Brown are on the right track here, you should consider staying away from hot reloading.

Comment: @Telastyn, the shared code would be accessed from an internal CDN, so it would only have to be deployed once. I guess what I'm trying to accomplish is like the dynamic code injection strategy common with JavaScript, but using C#. And no, I would never try to circumvent the change management policies.

Comment: @DocBrown, yes, bug fixes and similar modifications that affect all the services that rely on the code are the primary driver behind this effort.

Comment: @DavidArno, yes, I'm aware. Our company has not yet approved .NET 6 for use. I imagine they will soon (though we tend to be on the trailing edge of these things), and at that time, we'll update the framework.

Comment: @Flater, performance is a concern here, and the latency introduced with an out-of-process service, even if we leverage gRPC over HTTP/2, would be problematic.

Comment: _Something_ has got to give here. If you can't redeploy services with relative ease, don't want to redeploy many services, at the same time want to have 60+ services up and running, cannot bear the overhead cost of one service calling another service, and are squeezing for performance to the point that you just stated you don't even want any out-of-process services; then it just doesn't make any sense that you're using microservices at all. [..]

Comment: [..] If performance and single deploys are _this_ paramount while at the same time guaranteeing that all logic is updated simultaneously during a deploy, then a monolith would have a better lifecycle for your scenario. This is what I meant with my suspicion that you're tackling microservices wrongly. Microservices are not _better_ in every way, they are _different_. You are dealing with constraints that severely hamper what you can leverage from microservices. With those constraints, microservices just do not add enough benefit to warrant the effort required.

Comment: “Accessed from an internal CDN” - why do you think deployments are any different? You are reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Is there a reason or NFR that is behind why you rolled your own byte-array assembly loading scheme instead of using something like [shadow copying](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/shadow-copy-assemblies)? If you are using IIS this feature is already there out of the box.

Comment: Be advised that [FileSystemWatcher isn't always reliable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/240008/2791540)

Comment: @Flater, you're making the same argument I did when this requirement was first given to us: that this system was better kept as a monolith. Unfortunately, it's very difficult to convince our enterprise architecture team to deviate from their standards, even when an airtight argument can be made. I've escalated the argument as far as I can, and I'm left with two choices: comply or quit. Although many might advise otherwise, I'm choosing the former. ;-)

Comment: @JohnWu, you make a good point. I had investigated shadow copying quite a while ago and ran into some issues with it. TBH, I kind of forgot about it after that. I'll take another look. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @JohnWu, I've refreshed myself on shadow copying. The reason we didn't pursue it originally is that it only worked with AppDomains in .NET Framework. Microsoft did apparently include similar functionality in .NET 6 preview 3, but it only worked with IIS (which is not our host), and it sounds like even that has been removed in the final version. Some people claim to have been able to roll their own, so I may research that further. In any case, thanks again for your suggestion!

Comment: In my opinion, the main benefit of microservices are organizational. I.e. reduced inter-dependencies between different teams of *people*. My guess is that you do not have 60 teams developing the application. So microservices seem like a poor fit, and your attempts at circumventing it seems like a workaround to a problem in your organization. If your architecture team do not listen to good advice, it might be a question for https://workplace.stackexchange.com/